# WebApp with jQuery mobile hide addressbar don't work because google browser has a bug with height

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, hide, fullscreen, address-bar

When you hide the addressbar in WebbApps you got nearly the feeling of native Apps. Unfortunately, to hide the address bar works in jQuery mobile only if the content is large enough. If the content is too small it does not work - also with fullscreen and fixed footer - see http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html. Reason appears to be a bug in the browser in Android. If the content is too small the jQuery funktion $(window).height() delivers only 450px as screen height (I'm using Android 2.3.6 with a Galaxy S2). The height of the addressbar is missing. Is the content big enough the function delivers 508px - as expected. Also a quite good approach - http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/tags/jquery%20mobile -does not work. I found a solution which works but need a delay of 500ms. It brings a flipping adressbar when you load a page for a small time. Is there an another approch, that there is no flipping of the addressbar?

But maybe someone has an idea how this could work even better. And does it work well with iOS? It would be great if someone could test this with an iPhone.
Thanks in advance.

Here the code:

```
var fixgeometry = function() {                
            /* Calculate the geometry that our content area should take */
            var header = $(".header:visible");
            var footer = $(".footer:visible");
            var content = $(".content:visible");                
            var viewport_height = $(window).height()+60; /*Here is the idea! Make it bigger here and make it later smaller*/
            var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();

            /* Trim margin/border/padding height */
            content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
            content.height(content_height);
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.scrollTo(0, 1);
                content.height(content_height-60); }, 500 );
        };


$(document).ready(function(){                           
            $(window).bind("orientationchange resize pageshow", fixgeometry);   
      });
```

The scrollTo-function is implemented in jQuery, but it doesnt work after an oriantationchange or an input in a textfield. So its necessary here in the setTimeout-function.

Comment: I hope you have enough time to deal with this problem. $(window).height() and $(window).width() will give you viewport dimensions and they can vary from device to device and from browser to browser. Read this excellent article http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/ and maybe you will find a solution.